# unexpected flowtype error with possibly null object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am learning flow type, but I got a lot of problems that I do not understand.
One of them is as follows:
I initialize the `bill` state us `null` then I fetch it from the API and update the state with the fetched bill. I know that if `this.state.bill` is `null` I can't access any property on it so I only access properties of `this.state.bill` inside an `if` statement like that:

```
class BillPaymentPage extends Component<*, props, *> {
  state = {
    bill: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchBill(this.props.id);
  }

  fetchBill = async (id: string) => {
    const bill = await getBillById(id, this.props.token).catch(e =>
      console.log(e),
    );
    this.setState({ bill });
  };
  ....
  render() {
    if (this.state.bill) {
      const totalPayment = this.state.bill.payment
        .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.amount, 0)
        .toFixed(3);
      return (
        <Card>
          <PaymentForm
            bill={this.state.bill}
            submitPayment={this.submitPayment}
            billStatus={this.state.bill.status}
          />
          <h3>
            <FormattedMessage id="label.total" /> :{' '}
            <FormattedNumber
              value={this.state.bill.total}
              type="currency"
              currency="tnd"
            />
          </h3>
          <h3>
            <FormattedMessage id="label.totalPayment" /> :{' '}
            <FormattedNumber
              value={totalPayment}
              type="currency"
              currency="tnd"
            />
          </h3>
          <PaymentList
            deletePayment={this.deletePayment}
            payment={this.state.bill.payment}
          />
        </Card>
      );
    }
    return <Loader />;
  }
}
```

Although I've used `if(this.state.bill)` flow still show me this error:

```
app/components/pages/bills/BillPaymentPage.js:99
 99:             billStatus={this.state.bill.status}
                                             ^^^^^^ property `status`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
 99:             billStatus={this.state.bill.status}
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null

app/components/pages/bills/BillPaymentPage.js:104
104:               value={this.state.bill.total}
                                          ^^^^^ property `total`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
104:               value={this.state.bill.total}
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null

app/components/pages/bills/BillPaymentPage.js:119
119:             payment={this.state.bill.payment}
                                          ^^^^^^^ property `payment`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
119:             payment={this.state.bill.payment}
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^problem
```

[image]
How can I solve this probleme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow supports "refining" types, which means you can use control statements like `if` to make Flow realize that a certain option for a value is or is not available. This allows code like this to work fine:

```
var obj = {
  state: {
    bill: (null: null | { payment: Array<string> }),
  },
};

if (obj.state.bill) {
  let str: string = obj.state.bill.payment[0];
}
```

([On Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0G4QwTgBA9gRgVhAvBA3gKAhAzgFxDgUwC5UNMIYBLAG2pIAoA7AV1pJdogB9UIAHEAE8AtgUY4SAQTBghAHlxhKjAOYA+CAF8AlABoym-ZoDcaNJQBmEerDgA6XPgJ2qtbaUzUCObDjAlFZRUkaHgHPEIXGmo7ARExHABtAAYAXVNNIA))

because Flow can see that `.bill` can't be `null` because the `if` statement succeeded.

The reason that isn't happening in your case is that certain operations make Flow have to go back to being unsure. In your case it is

```
const totalPayment = this.state.bill.payment
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.amount, 0)
    .toFixed(3);
```

generally complex statements like this *could* somehow modify `bill` so that it was `null` again. In this particular instance it's obvious to a person that it won't happen, but it is not obvious to Flow. You can see that behavior in this too:

```
var obj = {
  state: {
    bill: (null: null | { payment: Array<string> }),
  },
};

if (obj.state.bill) {
  obj.state.bill.payment.reduce((acc, v) => v);

  let str: string = obj.state.bill.payment[0];
}
```

([On Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0G4QwTgBA9gRgVhAvBA3gKAhAzgFxDgUwC5UNMIYBLAG2pIAoA7AV1pJdogB9UIAHEAE8AtgUY4SAQTBghAHlxhKjAOYA+CAF8AlABoym-ZoDcaNJQBmEerDgA6XPgJ2qtbaUy2HeQi5rU7ARExHDswAgATZgBjAnp6EGjo3Qhgd0QNNNNMMmoCHGwcMBJFZRUkaHhvJz9aQKFRcQBtAAYAXVNNIA))

Generally the approach most people use for cases like this is that they pull the properties off of `state` entirely before using them, e.g.

```
var obj = {
  state: {
    bill: (null: null | { payment: Array<string> }),
  },
};


const { bill } = obj.state;

if (bill) {
  bill.payment.reduce((acc, v) => v);

  let str: string = bill.payment[0];
}
```

([On Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0G4QwTgBA9gRgVhAvBA3gKAhAzgFxDgUwC5UNMIYBLAG2pIAoA7AV1pJdogB9UIAHEAE8AtgUY4SAQTBghAHlxhKjAOYA+CAF8AlABoym-ZoDcaMwGMojXLyqdNSaPAB0ufAVNpKAMwj071NqkmAHOAiJiOM5gBAAmzOYE9PQg5ua6EMBBiBpZpphk1AQ42DhgJIrKKo6h4aLiANoADAC6pppAA))

which will work fine since there is not *no* way for the value of `bill` to change from non-`null` to `null` very obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Since your initial value for `this.state.bill` is null you cannot expect `this.state.bill.status` and the rest to work.

You might be mutating the value of `this.state.bill` later on via your asynchronous call, which might work fine, but the initial value being null is the problem.

To solve this, you could use some slick short-circuit syntax for when the value is still null:

```
<PaymentForm
  bill={this.state.bill}
  submitPayment={this.submitPayment}
  billStatus={(this.state.bill || {}).status || null}
/>
```

This basically means that `billStatus` will be either `this.state.bill.status` or `null` if `this.state.bill.status` is undefined

Do the same thing for the other components.

Comment: Thank you, but that did not solve the problem the same error persists.

Comment: @ziedhajsalah, what error do you get this time? Got a screenshot?

Comment: @ziedhajsalah, it doesn't look like you changed the code as I suggested. You need to change it **everywhere** where you use `this.state.bill.XXX`

Comment: @ziedhajsalah, it still doesn't look right. For example, on line 99 for `billStatus` you have `billStatus={this.state.bill.status || ''}`. This is not what I wrote in my answer. You need the new object notation. Try instead `billStatus={this.state.bill || {}).status || ''}`. Try only this change (line 99). Does the error on line 99 disappear after this change?